# need help in extracting the first google search result using html_node in R

Tags: r, hyperlink, extract, google-search

I have a list of hospital names for which I need to extract the first google search URL. Here is the code I'm using

```
library(rvest)
library(urltools)
library(RCurl)
library(httr)
getWebsite <- function(name)
{
 url = URLencode(paste0("https://www.google.com/search?q=",name))

 page <- read_html(url)

 results <- page %>% 
     html_nodes("cite") %>%
     html_text()

 result <- results[1]

 return(as.character(result))}
websites <- data.frame(Website = sapply(c,getWebsite))
View(websites)
```

For short URLs this code works fine but when the link is long and appears in R with "..." (ex. www.medicine.northwestern.edu/divisions/allergy-immunology/.../fellowship.html) it appears in the dataframe the same way with "...". How can I extract the actual URLs without "..."? Appreciate your help!

Comment: You can search for `html_nodes(".r")`, then for `html_nodes("a")` and then for `html_attr("href")` :)

Comment: Thanks but how would you search for all 3 in this code? Could you please send a working snippet?

Comment: Hi Tatiana, did my answer helps you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **This is a working example, tested on my computer:**

```
library("rvest")
# Load the page
main.page <- read_html(x = "https://www.google.com/search?q=software%20programming")
links <- main.page %>% 
  html_nodes(".r a") %>% # get the a nodes with an r class
  html_attr("href") # get the href attributes
#clean the text  
links = gsub('/url\\?q=','',sapply(strsplit(links[as.vector(grep('url',links))],split='&'),'[',1))
# as a dataframe
websites <- data.frame(links = links, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
View(websites)
```